# raspberry pi with webcam "corrupt jpeg data"

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, webcam

I wanted to try to make a undercranking with my raspberry pi and a old webcam (Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Communicate STX). But it didn't work: It showed me different errors, the the most frequent error is 'corrupt jpeg data: premature end of data segment'.
I added

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
```

(I have this tip from [raspberry pi motion webcam "premature end of data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664138/raspberry-pi-motion-webcam-premature-end-of-data)) and got the error 'bad huffman code'.

I'am a amateur at the raspberry, but I searched for a solution, but I had no found. The webcam work well on the computer and the raspberry pi can show me well pictures from the internet. But the pictures from the webcam taken with

```
fswebcam -r 1280x960 --jpeg 85 -q -d /dev/video0 testimg.jpg
```

(also with different sizes) are in a large part of image gray and in the upper half of the image the  content is  in pink or other colours. But I want only normal pictures...

Comment: Sounds like the data is YUV422, not RGB